# A point can be viewed as a circle?

Tags: analytic-geometry

In analytic geometry, can a point be viewed as a circle? In analytic geometry, can the point $(0, 0)$ be view as the circle of zero radius with center $(0, 0)$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)

Answer (score 3):

The equation $x^2+y^2=0^2$ has a single point as its solution. Whether that that means that a point "can be viewed as a circle" depends more on the exact meaning you assign to "can be viewed as" than on the nature of points and circles in themselves.

It certainly doesn't mean that all properties of circles are also properties of points. For example, a circle has the property that for every point on the circle there is exactly one line that passes through that point and not through other points on the circle. This is not true about a singleton set, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Every circle of radius $r$ and circumference $C$ satisfies $C/r = 2\pi$, but your "circle"  has $r=0$.